# "Global" XML settings in C#

Tags: c#, xml, settings, global

A settings file is a nice way to access important data anywhere in a program since we can simply say

`string dogType = Settings.Default.FavoriteDogType;` or `Settings.Default.FavoriteDogType = "Chiwawa";`

I like this but the file is managed by the computer (stored in user settings). For my application, I would like to allow the user to select there own settings file (stored by them) and use this file for the settings as in

```
NewWayOfUsingSettings.Load("bobsFavoriteDogInfo.xml");
```

and then being able to call

```
string dogType = NewWayOfUsingSettings.FavoriteDogType;
```

*anywhere* in the program where "bobsFavoriteDogInfo.xml" would contain the settings to use. (alternatively, Jane could load "JanesBestDog.xml" etc.) Does C# support a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I rarely ever look back at static members and go "that was a good thing".